# Wrapping a normal C function call in another static inline function?

Tags: c

I have seen code like the simplified example below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int myfunc(int a) {
    return a + rand();
}

static inline int myfunc_stat(void) {
    return myfunc(0);
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int intern = myfunc(0); //myfunc_stat();
    printf("intern is %d\n", intern);
    return 0;
}
```

... that is: there is a "normal" function `myfunc` that accepts a an argument; and then there is a `static inline` function `myfunc_stat` which does not receive arguments, and returns the return of the "normal" function called with the constant argument.

I was wondering - would there be any special benefits in "wrapping" a "normal" function in a "static inline" function as shown? At this time, I simply cannot see any difference - in principle, the way I see it, the compiler should just inline the call to `myfunc_stat` from main, and then there would be a "normal" call to `myfunc` from there.

But it seems, this example is so simple, I get exactly the same assembly, regardless of if I call `myfunc(0);` or `myfunc_stat();` in `main()`, from https://godbolt.org/z/M67PTnqeT - the compiler basically decides to inline both functions in either case.

But if the `myfunc` function was not so obviosly simple (or the build was not optimized), would there be some difference/side-effect/benefit to using a call to `myfunc_stat();` as opposed to `myfunc(0);` (aside from the purely semantic?)

Comment: `inline` is mostly unnecessary these days. The compiler will automatically generate inline code for simple functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If fifty calls to `foo()` within a program pass a constant value of zero, having them all call a non-inline function `foo_zero` which accepts no arguments, and which passes zero to `foo` will require generating code for `foo_zero`, but the generated code for each `foo_zero();` would likely be an instruction smaller than the code for each `foo(0);`.  On an ARM Cortex-M3, the code for `foo_zero()` would likely be six bytes, each call `foo_zero(0)` would take six bytes, and `foo_zero()` would take four.  If `foo(0)` would get called fifty times, that would likely save 94 bytes of code.

If, however, `foo_zero()` only got called twice, then the six bytes required for the generated code of `foo_zero()` would exceed the four bytes saved at other call sites, rendering this attempted optimization counter-productive.

If one is using a compiler that in-line expands functions which are declared `static inline`, but not others, then one could control whether machine code called `foo(0)` directly or created and used a `foo_zero()` wrapper.  Since the choice of which is optimal would depend on how much the function is used throughout a program, a compiler that examines source files in isolation would have no way to make that decision optimally.

Comment: There is very little reason to even consider this.

Comment: @user253751: In the embedded world, if one's product is expected to barely fit in a part with 8KB of code space, an easy 100-byte savings is nothing to sneeze at, especially when availability of larger parts is uncertain.

Comment: Thanks a ton - formulated like that, your answer makes a lot of sense to me; much appreciated!

Comment: [Well said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75176516/wrapping-a-normal-c-function-call-in-another-static-inline-function#comment132659603_75176734)